# Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense Keyboard Options

Tags: visual-studio-2015, autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts, intellisense

First, I'm asking this here, rather than on the Microsoft forums, because they're, well, you know what they are.

I like the VS2015 Intellisense autocomplete features -- when I want them.  But they've stupidly added the spacebar as a selection key.  Even more stupidly, they've added the '.' the ':' and probably other boundary characters as selection keys, too.

What this means, is I'm often typing happily along (and rather quickly), and whenever one of the "stupid" selection keys is pressed, I'm making intellisense selections I don't want.  I just want to type, dang it!  So I wind up having to go back and correct all the unintended autocomplete errors.

Microsoft "solves" this problem by allowing me to turn the whole thing off and bring it up with CTRL+J.  They won't let me change the settings to specify, say, only accepting intellisense options with the TAB key and nothing else.  Earlier versions permitted this.

My question is, is anyone aware of a plug-in or some other procedure that will allow me to modify the default behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle between "suggestion" and "completion" mode with **Edit > Intellisense > Toggle Completion Mode** or pressing `[Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Space]` (Keyboard shortcut can differ).

There is also a toolbar shortcut:
[image: Toolbar shortcut for autocompletion mode]

This will still pop up the completion list, but not automatically insert the highlighted entry when you press Return or Space. If you *want* to select an entry, use the arrow keys, the entry will then be selected (solid color highlight instead of outline) and work as before.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you want to type the following:

```
IceIceBaby
```

You type

```
Ice
```

VS2015 pops up with a box that says

```
IceCream
```

Just press the escape key and it will cancel and let you keep typing.

Comment: Thanks Cyber, but I know that, and it's still a pain.  I'm a fast typist, so by the time my brain even acknowledges a popup had appeared, I've typed one of the 'accept' characters and am often 5 or 6 characters on before I realize the mistake and have to back up to fix it.

Comment: Eventually you kinda get used to it.  I type 100+ wpm, you just gotta get used to the routine.  It took me awhile.

Comment: @Cyber wow 100++ wpm, I have been coding for about 6-7 years with 60 wpm, how do you manage to type 100++ wpm?